# MySQL en Git Bash Windows

Tags: mysql, git, windows

¿Saben cómo puedo usar MySQL desde Git Bash? Tengo instalado Xampp y estaba usando MySQL desde CMD pero me gustaría usarlo desde Git Bash. Al intentar ejecutarlo desde Git Bash me tira lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: El usuario no tiene contraseña.

Comment: buenas tarde te escrito el problema espero que te lo soluciones

Comment: O busca donde está el ejecutable y colocas el directorio en la variable $PATH.

Comment: No te olvides de darle la fecha arriba para saber que te ha servido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema con git bash y mysql, y la solución para esto es usar

```
winpty mysql -u root
```

Supongo que esto se debe a que está ejecutando mysql para windows, utilizando el entorno unix, y por lo que sé winpty debe ser utilizado para ejecutar aplicaciones de Windows en el git bash (no 100% seguro, tal vez alguien puede confirmar).

### Otra opción que tienes es :

Cree un acceso directo en el escritorio de Windows con este destino:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr \ bin \ mintty.exe" -e "C:\Program Files\Git\usr \ bin \ winpty.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.1\bin \ mysql.exe " - uroot-p
```

Answer (score 1):

En `bash`, aunque estés en Windows, cuando invocas un ejecutable ubicado en la carpeta en la que estás parado, tienes que anteponer la indicación de que se busque el comando en la carpeta actual: el `.` indica esto, entonces sería:

```
./mysql -u root
```

Otra forma es agregar al `path` la carpeta de los binarios de `mysql`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/c/xampp/mysql/bin"
```

Si quieres que esto sea permanente, debes agregar esta línea el el archivo de inicialización de bash: `.bashrc` en tu carpeta de usuario, para editar este archivo: `notepad ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso para no agregar el path logré ingresar usando la siguente variación:

```
winpty ./mysql -u root -p
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]